# Javascript: Remove whitespace between strings except one

Tags: javascript

There are two fields on one page (first name and last name) and one field on another page (org legal name). When the user types in the org legal name field I am checking whether the first name, last name, or a concatenation of the two matched what they are typing for the *org legal name*.

My concern is about the concatenation. Right now it is only testing the concatenation if there is one space between the names (ie. John Smith). But what if the user types multiple spaces in between by mistake?

I wrote the below method that attempts to match a first name, last name, or a concatenation of first and last names. It works but the problem is that it will only match the concatenation if there is one space between the strings. I need it to match in case the user mistakenly types multiple spaces between their first and last name?

```
validateFirstAndLastNameMatch() {
    const prospect = this.prospectService.getProspect();
    const firstName = prospect.prospectQuoteDto.firstName.toUpperCase();
    const lastName = prospect.prospectQuoteDto.lastName.toUpperCase();
    const orgLegalName = this.form.get('orgLegalName').value.trim().toUpperCase();
    if (firstName === orgLegalName || lastName === orgLegalName || firstName + " " + lastName === orgLegalName) {
      this.isMatchOnName = true;
    } else {
      this.isMatchOnName = false;
    }    
  }
```

Comment: Use a regular expression?

Comment: Not so good with regex's. Can you provide a working example?

Comment: To clarify — is there a single field in which the user will type their name? And maybe too many spaces between? e.g. `John . . Smith` ... also, dealing with names, be sure to read https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: so replace `\s+` with one....

Comment: So there are two fields on one page (first name and last name) and one field on another page (org legal name). When the user types in the org legal name field I am checking whether the first name, last name, or a concatenation of the two matched what they are typing.

Comment: My concern is about the concatenation. Right now it is only testing the concatenation if there is one space between the names (ie. John Smith). But what if the user types multiple spaces in between by mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match first name and last name combination, allow multiple spaces in between, ignore case.

```javascript
const pattern = new RegExp(firstName +"[ ]+" + lastName, "i");
const isLegal = pattern.test(orgLegalName);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! Can you explain how it works?

Comment: Glad to help. The `[ ]+` simply implies one or more spaces in the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression:

```js
const nameRegexp = /(\w+)(?:\s+(\w+))?/;

console.log(
  'joe'.match(nameRegexp),
  'joe schmoe'.match(nameRegexp),
  '  joe   schmoe '.match(nameRegexp)
);
```

Here's a breakdown of the regexp:

`(\w+)` - Match one or more letters for the first name.

`(?:\s+(\w+))?` - Optionally look for one or more spaces followed by one or more letters and match just the letters for the last name.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question properly, you can just trim the firstName and lastName before comparing them to orgLegalName

```
validateFirstAndLastNameMatch() {
const prospect = this.prospectService.getProspect();
const firstName = prospect.prospectQuoteDto.firstName.toUpperCase().trim();
const lastName = prospect.prospectQuoteDto.lastName.toUpperCase().trim();
const orgLegalName = this.form.get('orgLegalName').value.trim().toUpperCase();
if (firstName  === orgLegalName || lastName === orgLegalName || firstName + " " + lastName === orgLegalName) {
  this.isMatchOnName = true;
} else {
  this.isMatchOnName = false;
}
```

}

Comment: I think you misunderstood. So there are two fields on one page (first name and last name) and one field on another page (org legal name). When the user types in the org legal name field I am checking whether the first name, last name, or a concatenation of the two matched what they are typing. My concern is about the concatenation. Right now it is only testing the concatenation if there is one space between the names (ie. John Smith). But what if the user types multiple spaces in between by mistake?